# EJB Remote Method Invocation with client

Tags: ejb, client

I have got a problem with `ejb remote method invocation`. 
For testing I created a ejb project with a statless bean and a simple method, declared in a remote interface. I deployed this project in a JBoss 7.1.

Now I want to call the business method `hello` in my bean from another class, which is not part of the project and not deployed in that jboss server. So if I understand it correct, this is a normal remote method call from a client.

I wrote my HelloWorldClient, declared the properties for the InitialContext(). But when I run this client, I got a NameNotFoundException. For me it seems like the exception is because of a false jndi-name, but I tried a lot to get the correct one.

On the console I got jndi names from my server for the project, but it doesn't work. Could someone help me solve this problem?

Client with context:

```
Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
         jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
         jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
         jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
         jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
         jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpasswort");
         Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
         HelloWorldRemote hello = (HelloWorldRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global[/ejbproject1]/ejbproject1/HelloWorldBean[/HelloWorldRemote]");
```

My Bean:

```
@Stateless(name="hello")
public class HelloWorldBean implements HelloWorldRemote{

@Override
public String hello(String value) {
    System.out.println("Say hello to "+value);
    return "Hello " + value;
}
```

the jndi names from the jboss

```
18:19:07,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-6) JNDI bindings for session bean named hello in deployment unit deployment "ejbproject1.jar" are as follows:

java:global/ejbproject1/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
java:app/ejbproject1/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
java:module/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
java:jboss/exported/ejbproject1/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
java:global/ejbproject1/hello
java:app/ejbproject1/hello
java:module/hello
```

and the exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global[/ejbproject1]/ejbproject1/HelloWorldBean[/HelloWorldRemote] -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global[.ejbproject1].ejbproject1.HelloWorldBean[.HelloWorldRemote]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
java:global/ejbproject1/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
```

to

```
java:/ejbproject1/hello!interfaces.HelloWorldRemote
```

That will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, meanwhile I tried a different way, I use Maven to build. I added the projects as dependency and did the lookup directly in EJB-Injection